# my web page is not refreshing only for img src tag?

Tags: html, css

whenever i add a img src tag,my web page is not showing any change even after refreshing.Instead, if i copy the same code in a new file and save it with a new name,it shows changes. What should i do to have changes in my older html file?
here is my html code-

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="C:\Users\SHREYA\Desktop\portfolio\framework\css\css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-1">
              <div class="screenshot"><img src="C:\Users\SHREYA\Desktop\portfolio\toplist\images\app.png"></div>
              </div>
              <h1>text</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">image</div>
        </div>
              <p>FEATURED APP</p>
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">image</div>
              <div class="col-4">image</div>
              <div class="col-4">image</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my css code-

```
    *{
    border:1px solid red;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color:blue;
}

    h1{
        text-align:right;
        display:block;
    }
    .row{
        width:100%;
        display:flex;
    }
    .col-1{
        width:8.33%;
    }
    .col-2{
        width:16.66%;
    }
    .col-3{
        width:25%;
    }
    .col-4{
        width:33.33%;
    }
    .col-5{
        width:41.66%;
    }
    .col-6{
        width:50%;
    }
    .col-7{
        width:58.33%;
    }
    .col-8{
        width:66.66%;
    }
    .col-9{
        width:75%;
    }
    .col-10{
        width:83.33%;
    }
    .col-11{
        width:91.66%;
    }
    .col-12{
        width:100%;
    }
    .screenshot{
        max-width:8.33%;
        max-height:8.33%;
    }
    *{
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }
```

Comment: do you run code at localhost or at hosting?

Comment: What folder is your 'website' in? Try and link your image relatively - root-of-site->   '/images/image-name.png' - same with CSS

Comment: Have you confirmed the file you're editing is the file you have open? Two ways I can think of immediately to check for this include: (1) add some random text, save the file, and see if the text loads in the browser. (2) inspect element and see if the DOM element even exists.

Answer (score 0):

Change the absolute paths to relative paths

```
<link href="C:\Users\SHREYA\Desktop\portfolio\framework\css\css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<img src="C:\Users\SHREYA\Desktop\portfolio\toplist\images\app.png">
```

Maybe look like as follows

```
<link href="/framework/css/css1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<img src="/toplist/images/app.png">
```